# Vercel Next.js - third-party package fetch - CACHE MISS

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, serverless, vercel

I have many deployed projects on Vercel.com, recently I combined many common interfaces and apis in node_modules package.

All of my FETCH api have **revalidate** tag on fetch, **cache HIT** was every second time, now I do have **cache MISS** all the time.

**Next.js local build** however caches pages correctly

*Is there any configuration which I need to specify that I have fetch need to be cached in node_modules package*

My node package has both cjs and esm